# How to diagnose white screen on startup on Android device

Tags: android, ionic2

I've been developing my Ionic 2 app, running in the browser, and also running fine on the device with the debug build. `ionic -v` gives me `2.2.1`, and in package.json have...

```
"ionic-angular": "2.0.1",
"ionic-native": "2.4.1",
```

I wanted to start to test out a release build. I have create the keystore file etc and did some release builds.

Initially, I used `ionic build android --release` and installed this, and everything worked fine. After I discovered this does not minimize, and to do so I then built using `ionic build android --prod --release`. Looking in the .apk it is minimized as expected. I install it and the installs works fine.

However, when I run it, I just get the splash, and then a white screen, and that is it. I simplified my app.component.ts to remove all my startup logic, so I just hardwire to a new new near blank page, and now have nothing but the following in the MyApp constructor...

```
 this.platform.ready().then (() => {

    StatusBar.styleDefault();
    Splashscreen.hide();
  });
```

Still nothing. I created a blank app, and tried the same build (ie `ionic build android --prod --release`), and that worked fine.

So, there must be something in mine. But this only occurs in the minified release, so I can't debug into it (or didn't seem to be able to). I am not sure how to track down what the error could be. Are there any startup logs etc?
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't you still be able to output to developer console with `console.log()`? That might help you catch where the app stalls.

Comment: @schlaus  I ran adb logcat but didn't see any errors. The thing is it doesn't even seem to get to any of my code. I removed everything in the startup to see if at least app.html is loaded, which it doesn't seem to be (I put just a simple string in there). I am new to this so not sure where the developer console is? Could there be some errors (eg Angular or Ionic) in there?

Comment: If you hook your phone to a computer, launch Chrome and navigate to `chrome://inspect` you can pick your app from the list and view errors in Chrome's console (`F12` on Win). If you're running it in production mode you may have to go through some extra steps to enable debugging.

Comment: I tried the above with `chrome://inspect` but I do not see it there when I have it running after building with the `--prod --release` flags.